# Nexus OOS 2 as proxy for ivy artifacts

Tags: playframework, sbt, nexus, ivy

task:
we would like to configure local Nexus as proxy for our application.
Actually our app based on Play2 framework, and it use sbt for building. As I understood, sbt use ivy repos for artifacts, and currently I have all this artifacts in my home dir:

```
ostetsiak@spyro ~ $ ll ~/.ivy2/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x   3 ostetsiak ostetsiak  4096 Jul  4 12:49 ./
drwxr-xr-x  50 ostetsiak ostetsiak  4096 Aug 15 10:39 ../
drwxr-xr-x 144 ostetsiak ostetsiak 12288 Aug 17 12:42 cache/
-rw-r--r--   1 ostetsiak ostetsiak     0 Jul  4 12:49 .sbt.cache.lock
-rw-r--r--   1 ostetsiak ostetsiak     0 Aug 17 12:44 .sbt.ivy.lock
ostetsiak@spyro ~ $
```

I did not succeed with [this](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/sbt.html) and [this](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html) manual, it does not work,
probably some body know how to do this, and I am not sure that Nexus supports ivy artifacts

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the [document](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/sbt.html) you quoted answers your last question:

> [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) has a built in dependency management component and defaults to the
>   Maven repository format.

Nexus is a Maven repository manager, so yes, it's capable of being used with sbt.[Apache ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/) is just an underlying tool used by sbt to manage its dependencies.

I suggest you read the following sbt guides, to first understand how sbt works:

1. [.sbt build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def.html)
2. [scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Scopes.html)
3. [More kinds of setting](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/More-About-Settings.html)
4. [Library dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html)